# Testing a TCL package; Tuning it for efficiency

Tags: unit-testing, tcl

I have written / rewritten a package and want to fully test it and do not know how to do so. Specifically when large amounts of data are loaded into the package it slows to a crawl.

I have posted the Code at [wiki.tcl.tk](http://wiki.tcl.tk/14468)

For the test assume that you have 12 columns & 10,000 rows.
where I run into an issue is `Tcl2ExXML::outputXML`. 
How would you go about testing this and fixing where it is crawling at?

```
set Test_WB         "";
set Test_WS         "";
set ErrorHeadder    "";
set ErrorText       "";
set NormalHeadder   "";
set DateCol         "";

set Test_WB     [Tcl2ExXML::CreateWorkbook      "MassOrderLoad_[clock format [clock seconds] -format %Y%m%d%H%M%S]"]
set Test_WS     [Tcl2ExXML::CreateWorkSheet     $Test_WB "TestWS-[clock format [clock seconds] -format %Y-%m-%d]"]
set ErrorHeadder       [Tcl2ExXML::CreateStyle         $Test_WB -algnmt {-v bottom -h center} -font {-nm "Calibri" -ff "Swiss" -sz 14 -fc #FF0000 -b 1} -border {{top bottom left} -ls "continuous" -lw 3} -interior {-ic #DCE6F1 -ip "Solid"}]
set ErrorText          [Tcl2ExXML::CreateStyle         $Test_WB -algnmt {-v bottom -h center} -wrap 1 -font {-nm "Calibri" -ff "Swiss" -sz 11 -fc #FF0000}]
set NormalHeadder      [Tcl2ExXML::CreateStyle         $Test_WB -algnmt {-v bottom -h center} -font {-nm "Calibri" -ff "Swiss" -sz 14 -fc #000000 -b 1} -border {-bp {top bottom} -ls "continuous" -lw 3 -bp {left right} -ls "continuous" -lw 1} -interior {-ic #DCE6F1 -ip "Solid"}]
set DateCol            [Tcl2ExXML::CreateStyle         $Test_WB -datafmt ymd]
                        Tcl2ExXML::setColumnAttributes $Test_WS 26 -s $DateCol
                        Tcl2ExXML::setColumnAttributes $Test_WS 27 -s $DateCol
set RowNum             [Tcl2ExXML::addRow $Test_WS -s $ErrorHeadder ERROR_MSG -s $NormalHeadder OPERATION  \
                                                   -s $NormalHeadder RowData_1 -s $NormalHeadder RowData_2 \
                                                   -s $NormalHeadder RowData_3 -s $NormalHeadder RowData_4 \
                                                   -s $NormalHeadder RowData_5 -s $NormalHeadder RowData_6 \
                                                   -s $NormalHeadder RowData_7 -s $NormalHeadder RowData_8 \
                                                   -s $NormalHeadder RowData_9 -s $NormalHeadder RowData_10]

foreach Row $DataList
    lassign $Row C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  C9  C10 C11 C12
    set RowNum             [Tcl2ExXML::addRow $Test_WS -s $ErrorText $C1 $C2 $C3 $C4 $C5 $C6 $C7 $C8 $C9 $C10 $C11 $C12]
}

set XML [Tcl2ExXML::outputXML $Test_WB]
puts "XML Created, Cleaning up."
puts $Chan $XML
close $Chan

Tcl2ExXML::DeleteWorkbook $Test_WB
```

Comment: Your `outputXML` command creates XML by sequentially invoking `append`  thousands of times to build a string containing XML text. That is always going to take some time. Use something like `tDOM` instead to build the DOM structure of the document and have it generate the XML text when you are done.

Comment: I will look into how this can be implemented. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a large thing you're asking for here and there's all sorts of things that could be issues. Could you split the problem up into smaller pieces and measure them on their own? Try to figure out where the critical problems are? (The `time` command will help you get some hard data.)

If the fundamental problem is just that the output is large, writing it to a temporary file might be the best option. But that's not necessarily going to help either.

Having scanned through, I see some potentially expensive operations. In particular, `clock format` and `array names` are not known for being cheap. Doesn't mean that they're the problem though. That drilling down step I mentioned above is critical.

Comment: Thanks @Donal for replying. Like I said I think that it is mainly the Tcl2ExXML::outputXML function that is delaying the whole process. I thought about using SpeedTables from Flight Aware but that would require a complete rewrite and I would need to study how they work as I have never used them. I have been looking through results using the Activestate TCL debugger. But have limited knowledge on proper use on that is as well.

Comment: I will wrap portions with `time` and see what I come up with. Are there any other pointers you can lend?

Comment: There's so many options that it _could_ be that picking a small set to try is really hard. Narrow down where the bottleneck is first. (Also, exactly which version of Tcl are you using? The profile of what is fast and what isn't has changed over time.)

Comment: I am using tcl 8.6